# Keyboard Delete Button not working for textbox inside object which is inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, internet-explorer-10, object-tag

I have three pages (HTML documents) as following:

1. Page1 : contains only one textbox.
2. Page2 : contains object tag which using the "data" attribute calls Page1.
3. Page3 : contains iframe tag which using the "src" attribute calls Page2.

Open Page3 in IE 10 or IE 11.

> Now the issue is that the keyboard's delete button is not working inside the textbox.

By seeing the structure you can understand how complicate project I am working on and I can not change this structure without introducing a lot performance issues.

I'll appreciate if any one can tell me why this is happening in IE 10/11 and not in IE8/Chrome/Firefox?

Comment: Hi,I am also getting the same issue..Have you fixed it?

Comment: No, I used used <iframe> in place of <object> as a workaround. But is downgraded the performance of my application.